# Way to make Dropdown Form Fields required in semantic ui react

Tags: semantic-ui-react

I have a Form, Is there a way to make these Dropdown Fields required?

Comment: please do update your question with the codew

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to make a Dropdown field required :

```js
<Form.DropDown
  required
  fluid
  label='Required Dropdown'
  options={options}
/>
```

Comment: Adding `required` inside `Form.Dropdown` is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge i dont think "required" works with Form.select in semantic ui.
What we can do is use if and else in the handleSubmit function and not let the function run when Form.select is empty and show a relevant message to the user.